# How do you debug Smarty application?

Tags: php, smarty

if there have an error in Smarty application, the page always display nothing in browser, How could i debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked [Smarty's page on Troubleshooting](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/troubleshooting.tpl)? PHP's error reporting might also be turned off or modified. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php. The php.ini `display_errors` setting could be turned off.

Answer (score 0):

See `Smarty doc` its help you

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/chapter.debugging.console.tpl